# xamarin ios app crashing with CBCentralManager

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a Fresh application with basically no code added to it except the following Code.
If I try it in a simulator it goes into update state and says unsupported.
If I try to run in on a 6 generation ipad (with bluetooth turned on) the application crashes as soon as debugging exits UIButton231_TouchUpInside (and never goes into the catch).

Am I missing anything?

```
        CBCentralManager _central;
    partial void UIButton231_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        try
        {
            BluetoothLEManager();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }

    protected void BluetoothLEManager()
    {
        try
        {
            _central = new CBCentralManager(DispatchQueue.CurrentQueue);
            _central.DiscoveredPeripheral += (object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DiscoveredPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("RSSI: " + e.Peripheral.RSSI);
            };

            _central.UpdatedState += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("UpdatedState: " + _central.State);
            };


            _central.ConnectedPeripheral += (object sender, CBPeripheralEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ConnectedPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);

            };

            _central.DisconnectedPeripheral += (object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DisconnectedPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }
```

In the Image below (code is compacted to make the image shorter), debugging reaches line 62 just fine, but attempting to step over or to just let it continue will close the application, and breakpoints in the catch are not reached.

[image]

Comment: Hi , could you get the crash log or you can share the creah screenshot .

Comment: There is no crash screen. On the ipad the app just closes. I edited my post above to show the failure point while debugging.... I was not able to find anything about bluetooth in the entitlement.plist.... Is there an equivalent on xamarin.ios to the "uses-feature" in the android manifest?

Comment: Do you mean the [iOS Security and Privacy Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows#setting-privacy-keys) of `info.plist` in Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: That is what I meant, but I tried adding
 <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>peer-peer</string>
  <string>bluetooth-le</string>
  <string>location-services</string>
 </array>
With no luck. The behaviour is still same....

Comment: OK , I will check it in local site. If solution will share here .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried shared code in local site , and it also crashes and with some error logs :

### [image: Crash logs]

After checking this line error :

> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.

Sometimes that may be caused by permission in iOS . You can have a look at this aticle by James : **[New iOS 10 Privacy Permission Settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/)** .

> Starting in iOS 10, nearly all APIs that require requesting authorization and other APIs, such as opening the camera or photo gallery, require a new key value pair to describe their usage in the Info.plist.

However , in `info.plist` , you can add the permission of Bluetooth easily as follow and will forget another most important permission :

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add BlueTooth Peripheral Permission</string>
```

That's not enough for Bluetooth . You also need to add another permission :

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>use Bluetooth</string>
```

From native `info.plist` , you also will find it .

[image]

This permission is fundamental and necessary . Because this will pop up a permission Dialog window in iOS device .

[image]

**By the way** , there is [an offical API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corebluetooth?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#remarks) about using Bluetooth in Xamarin iOS you can have a look .

```
public class MySimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
        override public void UpdatedState (CBCentralManager mgr)
        {
            if (mgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn) {
                //Passing in null scans for all peripherals. Peripherals can be targeted by using CBUIIDs
                CBUUID[] cbuuids = null;
                mgr.ScanForPeripherals (cbuuids); //Initiates async calls of DiscoveredPeripheral
                //Timeout after 30 seconds
                var timer = new Timer (30 * 1000);
                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => mgr.StopScan();
            } else {
                //Invalid state -- Bluetooth powered down, unavailable, etc.
                System.Console.WriteLine ("Bluetooth is not available");
            }
        }
    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral (CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Discovered {0}, data {1}, RSSI {2}", peripheral.Name, advertisementData, RSSI);
    }

}
public partial class HelloBluetoothCSharpViewController : UIViewController
{
MySimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate myDel;
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

  //Important to retain reference, else will be GC'ed
        myDel = new MySimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate ();
        var myMgr = new CBCentralManager (myDel, DispatchQueue.CurrentQueue);

    }
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! I really appreciate your effort with me.

Comment: Junior Jiang - I implemented the above same code, and its discovered the nearest available devices, but peripheral.name and its UUID is always empty. I am able to get the ".data and RSSI" only not UUID and its Name why? Could you help

Comment: @Prasanth Hi , have a check whether bluetooth device whether setted name first . Then using another mobile to test that whehter works .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I tried its not working, also I have one more doubt - Using the above code its displaying only Apple/iOS devices, but I want non-Apple products also. As same as default - iOS Bluetooth search. I know it should communicate the exact same protocol devices only. Could you please suggest which Bluetooth Dongle is able to detect from iOS code(product /manufacturer name).  Actually I want to communicate from iOS device to Windows PC via external Bluetooth Dongle. Any idea please help me. Sorry for the late message

Comment: @Prasanth Okey, sorry for not familiar with this scene . Generally , iOS device can detect all the bluetooth devices no matter whether it's a non-apple products , such as a bluetooth watch , earphone , etc .  I think there is no limitation of them to connect to apple device via bluetooth . I think the only thing that can be done is to ensure that the signal of the Bluetooth peripheral is relatively stable and the signal strength is also stronger. That will be more conducive to later work.