# Can any one help me to solve this error in iOS 13.5.1 devices for using CoreBluetooth for ble transmission

Tags: ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

## =================================================================
Native Crash Reporting

Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

=================================================================

## =================================================================
Native stacktrace:

```
0x102be67e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/632E2F9B-5F56-490A-84DB-57766748357A/AirLocation.app/AirLocation : 
0x102bdd47c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/632E2F9B-5F56-490A-84DB-57766748357A/AirLocation.app/AirLocation : 
0x102be5d2c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/632E2F9B-5F56-490A-84DB-57766748357A/AirLocation.app/AirLocation : 
0x1b7fb6894 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b80a5e58 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b80a5e88 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
0x1be503c8c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
0x1be503bcc - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
0x1be507b00 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
0x1b7e80be4 - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b7e754b0 - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b7f735a4 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b7f314f0 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b7f290c8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
0x1b7fc4bac - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_wqthread
0x1b7fc7740 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : start_wqthread
```

Comment: Hi ,  you can have a look at this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045636/xamarin-ios-app-crashing-with-cbcentralmanager/60068329#60068329 whether be helpful to solve your problem .

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below keys to your app's **Info.plist** file should solve this issue.

```
Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description
Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description
```

The key `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` is required from iOS 13 from Xcode 11.
It looks like your application might be being killed by iOS for trying to use Bluetooth while it is not allowed to.
Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth)

Comment: This solution I have tried but didn't work still getting same error, Is there any update.

Comment: This worked for me.  How did you know it was the BLE descriptions from the error above?